# IPod Touch says it's disabled for 22,768,662 minutes

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod Touch that says it is disabled and to try again in 22,768,662 minutes.  I really don't have 42 years to wait.  I need to access this iPod Touch and the material inside it without factory resetting it.  Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by syncing with iTunes then restoring, just follow [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212) handy guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have not officially tested this, however I have seen this same answer on a couple sites, so I thought I'd share it here.

There is a way to erase the password without erasing your files. Plug in your iPod. Open My Computer (or Computer for Windows 7). Click on Folder options and enable to view hidden files. Next go to iPod_control and click on the folder named Device. If your iPod is locked, there will be a file _locked . Rename the file to _unlocked. Remove your iPod and it should be cleared.

Again, I have never tested this. Please let me know if this process is no longer available, and I'll graciously remove this answer.